# How to compose, wrapped and parameterised Function1 instances using Shapeless library

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-cats

I am trying to build a composer utility for a range of WorkItems, based on Shapeless HList

```
class WorkItem[-A, B](name: String)(val work: A => B) {
// some additional methods

def andThen[C](anotherWork: WorkItem[B, C]): WorkItem[A,C] = {
// using cat's arrow compose
WorkItem(anotherWork.name)(self.work >>> anotherWork.work)
}
}
```

Lets say, I have following list of workItems:

```
val workItem1: WorkItem[Int, String] = { .... }
val workItem2: WorkItem[String, Double] = { ..... }
val workItems3: WorkItem[Double, Int] = { ..... }
```

I would want to build the composer functionality over HList of WorkItem(s) which reduces the above list of workItems to **WorkItem[Int, Int]**

```
object WorkItemComposer {
def compose[A, B, C, L <: HList](workItems: L): WorkItem[A, C] {
/// some magic
}
}
```

so that,

```
WorkItemComposer.compose(HList(workItem1, workItem2, workItem3)) should return WorkItem[Int, Int]
```

I have tried creating a Ploy2 instance as,

```
object WorkItemCompose extends Poly2 {
  implicit def composedFunctions[A, B, C]: Case[WorkItem[A, B], WorkItem[B, C]] {
    type Result = WorkItem[A, C]
  } =
    use{ (x: WorkItem[A, B], y: WorkItem[B, C]) => x andThen y }
}
```

```
Object WorkItemComposer {
import ops.hlist._

def compose[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit reducer: LeftReducer[L, WorkItemCompose.type]): reducer.Out =
  reducer(l)
}
```

I am not able to provide proper implicits for the method to perform *andThen* over every element of the HList. Hence below code is throwing a compile time error of,

> **could not find implicit value for parameter reducer: shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftReducer[WorkItem[Int,String] :: WorkItem[String,Double] :: WorkItem[Double,Int] :: shapeless.HNil, WorkItemCompose.type]**
> val finalTester= WorkItemComposer.compose(createStringValue :: createDoubleValue :: createIntValue :: HNil)

I am sure that I am missing the part of letting the compiler know that we can traverse thru the HList and apply WorkItemCompose to reduce the list to a Work Item. However, I am not able to close the gap given my lack of experience with shapeless library and available capabilities.

Could someone please help me fill the gaps in my implementation?

Comment: Your approach is workable, it compiles and runs as expected for me (Scala 2.13, shapeless 2.3.7).

Comment: Confirm that the code compiles: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/hjVvl2fMRtqAS042F1d6og

Comment: Strange! It worked after invalidating the caches and restarted Intellij IDE. It started to work fine. Thank you very much for helping me with this.

Comment: Asking out of curiosity and honestly doesn't have such requirement. Would you think the same code works for all subclasses of WorkItem ?